# Comparing strings with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am comparing strings with `.Contains()` but I found a problem:

```
foreach (var pair in cluster)
{
    if (pair.Key.Contains("a" + i.ToString()))
    {
         vlr = pair.Value;
    }
}
```

"a10", "a11", "a1.." are retrieving when I search "a1".
There is another way to compare diferente of `==`

Comment: I forgot! using contais: pair.key is ("a5-a6", "a1-a8", "a10-a7") and the error occours when I need to find "a1".... The code must retrieve only "a1-a8" and not "a1-a8" and "a10-a7". I guess I have to splitted .Split('-') and compare both results separated...

Comment: It would be more helpful if you edited your question with that detail rather than burying it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to make sure that your search string is an isolated substring, not a prefix or a suffix of a larger substring, you can use regular expressions. For example, to see if a string contains `a5` but not `a52` or `xa5`, you can do this:

```
if (Regex.Matches(input, "\\ba5\\b").Count > 0) ...
```

Here is an example:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches("hello a5 world", "\\ba5\\b").Count > 0);  // True
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches("hello a55 world", "\\ba5\\b").Count > 0); // False
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches("hello xa5 world", "\\ba5\\b").Count > 0); // False
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/DvWpwP).

Regex is versatile enough to let you adjust the expression to your needs: you can use [positive and negative lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). For example, if you need to make sure that `5` is *not* followed by another digit, you can write `"a5(?!\\d)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I think the query you're looking for is:

```
var query = cluster.Where(kvp => kvp.Key
                                    .Split('-')
                                    .Contains("a" + i.ToString())  // Array.Contains, not String.Contains
                         )
                   .Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Contains()` checks if the string contains a sub string in it or string

if you trying to see if they are equal or not you should use somethink like

```
if (pair.Key.Equals(i.ToString()))
```

or

```
string.Compare(pair.Key, i.ToString()) == 0
```